# i cant Indexed category/products association in magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, category, indexing

Hi maybe someone can help me I’m having a problem with Indexed category/products association i try just about everything people say and it’s not working  this is what I did so far and not working

- System -> Configuration > Manage Stores > the Store Name click on Main Website Store. >Default Category

  It’s on the right one and I redo it just to make sure
- i also try to change the permission set to tmp folder.  /var/locks  from 777 to 755 and still not working

Does anyone have any more ideas that I can fix this problem??

Thank you
  Danny

Answer (score 0):

Is there Error page? Or maybe some logs in var/report?

What message have in Index Status page?

How many products you have? Maybe it take too long?

What permission you have?(Can you run SSH on this server? Reindex can be done via command line so take less time and don't stop because of max execution time of php files and less errors at all)